# delete a specific google maps marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, marker

I'm using the Google Maps API for a web app and I'm  trying to delete a single group of markers depending on the input distance, but all I can do is delete all markers with the following code I found in the google Api's documentation:

```
clearMarkers();

  markers = [];
```

how can I keep track of every marker and delete/hide it individually?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
marker.setMap(null);
```

to each of the markers that you wanna hide in the array.

for example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    if (markers[i].filter == filter)
    {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
    else
    {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the markers and call a function or do your input-distance test on each marker, and then set the map to null if the test fails.

```
markers.forEach(function(m) {
  if (!matchesInputDistance(m)) {
     m.setMap(null)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function clearMarkerSelected() {
                if (markerSelected) {
                    markerSelected.setEditable(false);
                    markerSelected = null;
                }
            }

function setMarker(marker) {
                    markerSelected = marker;
                    marker.setDraggable(true);
                }
google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function () {
                            setMarker(newShape);
                        });
```